# Unknown lvalue 'FailureAction' in section 'Unit'; Unknown lvalue 'SuccessAction' in section 'Unit'

Tags: centos, systemd

systemd shows me this in my journal

```
Unknown lvalue 'FailureAction' in section 'Unit'
Unknown lvalue 'SuccessAction' in section 'Unit'
```

What is causing this?

Currently using systemd `219`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SuccessAction` and `FailureAction` came in with SystemD version 236.

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS#L3941